# Route groups for localization in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have three languages on my site:

```
en, fr, de
```

I want all of the pages on the site to have the language in the url in the first segment, ie.

```
/page     ->set Locale as English
/de/page  ->set Locale as German
/fr/page  ->set Locale as French
```

Any idea how I can apply this to all routes? The language must be set based on the first URL segment, if its not 'de' or 'fr' then set the language as English. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be okay to have one set of routes for English and one set of routes for everything else?  I can't get it to work using a route group optional prefix when the prefix isn't there.  Otherwise your only other option is to put the language at the end.

Comment: yes it might, but let me ask you something, how to constrain the route group to only "fr" and "de" 

`Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () { })->where('lang', '[fr|de]');`

This code is imaginary... `Route::group()` cannot append `->where()` to it

Comment: I'd probably use middleware to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working now with a foreach loop.

```
<?php

// routes.php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'lang'], function () {

    $langPrefixes = array_merge(config('app.langs'), ['']);

    foreach ($langPrefixes as $lang)
    {
        Route::get($lang . '/', [
            'uses' => 'PropertyController@index'
        ]);

        Route::get($lang . '/stuff', [
            'uses' => 'PropertyController@stuff'
        ]);
    }

});
```

In config/app.php:

```
<?php

// config/app.php

'langs' => ['fr', 'de'], // new addition
```

And middleware:

```
<?php

// Middleware/SetLanguage.php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class SetLanguage
{
    protected $app;

    /**
     * Get access to the IoC container
     *
     * @param  Illuminate\Foundation\Application  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (in_array($request->segment(1), $this->app['config']['app.langs']) )
        {
            // override 'en' as the app locale
            $this->app['config']['app.locale'] = $request->segment(1);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```